# How to run the browserstack inspected element with java through Appium?

Tags: java, appium, browserstack

I am trying to find an element through Appium inspector, but the DOM tree is not expanding for the particular element. Using Browserstack inspector I am able to inspect the element. But while running the java code with BrowserStack inspected element through Appium, I am not able to progress. can anyone help me with this??

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Appium desktop to inspect the app?

https://www.browserstack.com/docs/app-automate/appium/integrations/appium-desktop

Are you testing a Flutter Application? Appium has a known issue when testing Flutter based apps and shows similar behavior wherein the element tree does not expand

Comment: Yes I am using Appium desktop